# cics where to start for develop a monitoring tool

Tags: monitoring, cics

where can i start if I want to write a "self-made monitoring tool" to trace CICS transaction at the maximum level of detail?
I know there is SMF but it doesn't give me information about single programs invoked by the main. 
I also know that there are specialized tools(Sysview, mainview and other) but i'm interesting to know how they work and try to create my one.

I've tried to make some searches but i stil don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Yuri said, it is worth doing if for nothing else other than gaining a deeper understanding of how CICS works, writing a full on detailed monitor is probably not a viable commercial prospect, but thats your call. If you are not a sysprog already than maybe you should be thinking about it. Almost all of what is described below will only be available with suitable access

Be clear in what you want to achieve, tracing and monitoring are different in CICS and the types of data collected are kept in different areas with different purposes 
For a start there is monitor data and trace data. Monitor data is collected at points like task termination and timed intervals, the data is stored in the monitor buffers and ends up in SMF and, as you state, does not show you the various programs called within a task execution. 
Trace data on the other hand is highly detailed covering every interaction of a task with CICS and CICS internals. Trace data is stored in memory in the Trace Table and can optionally be written by CICS to the auxiliary trace datasets. The downside of trace data is that it is produced at a tremendous rate so capturing and storing this data would be onerous to perform youself. 
Finally information can be gathered from the various CICS control blocks like which tasks are active, their state etc. This is real time since this relects system state but only at a point in time. You couldnt use this for to track programs used by a task since you have no idea how many programs have been run between scans of the control blocks 
In the case of monitoring and trace information the collection and storage of this data is performed by CICS for you as about efficiently as can be done, it doesn't make sense to re-invent those wheels. But you can add some extra ones.

All the CICS monitoring products out there do things the same way. Gather data from the CICS monitor area (read up on CMF) and CICS control blocks (read up on CICS domain APIs) and then also hook into the CICS global exit points (GLUEs) to get extra counter and timing information (such as tracking program names). The gathered information is then passed to an external address space for storage/presentation. Some of the ways to gather the information are not readily available so producing an Omegamon equivalent would be difficult. 
Having said all of that if you still want to dig around then use the Customisation Guide to look up the monitoring falitity (CMF). In particular you may be interested in coding up GLUEs for intercepting program start/end e.g. exit point XPCFTCH, yes its assembler, and putting in EMP calls and activating them in the MCT, this will help you produce program names and timings within a task through the CICS Resource records

Look at using CICS supplied utility DFH$MOLS to process the SMF data, if you are on 5.3 than it will offload into a data format that you could find useful to process

Look at writing some trace data to the auxiliary trace data set using transaction CETR and process the data with utility DFHTUxxx where xxx is the version of cics you are running e.g. DFHTU700 for CICS 5.3. have a look at what you get and whether you can use it

For control block information look at CICS Data Areas, accessing them is your challenge.

I can only repeat as said by others. Dont do this in production, or probably not any environment that is expected to stay active! You may well not have authorisation levels to do much of this. Speak to the systems programmers, a lot of this may already be there.

But here is a curved ball. If what you are really looking for is tracking of an application like say an automated CEDF then look at CICS Event processing in Emitter mode, that would be interesting

Answer (score 1):

How products such as MainView, etc. *actually* work I cannot say; I recommend you don't attempt this.  Likely it would violate HIPAA and SOX and all sorts of other auditor hot-button legislation.

CICS provides user exit points so Assembler code you write can get control, i.e. before and/or after an `EXEC CICS` call.

The exit points and how to write the Assembler code are documented by IBM in the Knowledge Center for CICS. There are also exit points for some z/OS services.

It might be interesting reading, and you *may* get some insight into how these products *possibly* work, but please don't think your CICS Systems Programmer is going to thank you for writing such code.

Just don't.

Answer (score 1):

You start at *CICS Customization Guide* for your CICS version. Almost everything you need to understand about CICS monitoring at the deepest level is there, including virtually everything vendor products use. Assembler is a must.

If you have a CICS development environment with enough authorization, you can try things out. That's fun and educating, and you will *definitely* become a better CICS programmer at any level by learning this. Just be careful - this stuff can easily bring CICS down, or mess up with the application code, or corrupt data. Don't try it anywhere near production. Even in dev, make sure your sysprog knows about it. Ask for a sandbox - that's ideal.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Read the other caveats for doing this online in a CICS system, plus add in performance concerns.

The answer to your question will depend on **why** you want to do this. Don't forget about CICS trace - this will show all the information you could ever possibly need. It's much less risky to take a trace and look at it offline - possibly with a home-grown formatting tool if that's what you want to write.

It's not an online monitoring solution, but may satisfy your personal curiosity / application insight requirements.